# Change icon color in cupertino_icons

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I make a two color icon in the `cupertino_icons` library? For example, so that the sun is yellow at a white cloud?

[image]

Comment: You cannot really do that. You see, those are actually glyphs part of the "CupertinoIcons" font: https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/c5e4b74691cca32a5a133857407f9555c5e1242e/third_party/packages/cupertino_icons/assets

Comment: In that case, I think you need to create one. Because `Icon`  takes only one parameter. Or we can do something with stack :).

Comment: @YeasinSheikh that will do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OutPut**

[image: result]

**Code**

```
 Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 44 * 1.3,
                  width: 44 * 1.3,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.sun_min_fill,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          size: 44,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.cloud_bolt_fill,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 44,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a pity that there is only such a way. Do you happen to know what happened to the link https://flutter.github.io/cupertino_icons? I have a 404 error.

Comment: You can check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoIcons-class.html

Comment: instead of icons, I have inscriptions :( You too?

Comment: Sorry I'm not aware of it, you can also check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/icons.dart

Answer (score 0):

You can also create different themes, like:

```dart
// In filename lib/config/styles.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Palette {
  static const Color background = Color(0xFFF0F0E4);
  static const Color secondaryBackground = Color(0xFFE7E4D3);
  static const Color green = Color(0xFF2AAF61);
}

class AppTheme {
  static ThemeData lightTheme() => ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Palette.background,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Palette.background,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          accentColor: Palette.green,
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      );
}
```

Then to `MaterialApp` widget put the theme, like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'config/styles.dart';
import 'presentation/screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Title',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme(),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```